# Observable.then() not working on real device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, observable

I have an Ionic app that correctly works  in the IonicLab, both while running and debugging it.

The same code, when run or debugged on a real Android device, fails to initialize the argument in one of the `then()` callbacks of an `Observable`. Most other (I suspect all other) `Observable` instances around my code do work correctly.

If I were to guess the cause, I'd say that non-working-on-real-device `Observable` is *too nested* into a chain of enclosing `Promises`, but that's just a random guess by a random Angular newbie.

Here is what I see when I debug the app attached to the real Android device:

[image]

As you can see, the `profile` variable is `undefined`, but, as I understand how `Observable.then()` works, it should have a value, as it in fact does have when run in the IonicLab.

What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is with `then`, rather than with `getProfile()` failing to resolve its returned promise with a proper value?

Comment: Well, obviously the fact that I'm the grandmaster of all the fools in the world... thanks a lot, that was the problem ahahah

Comment: No worries, it can be hard to be aware of what we take for granted and start questioning it :)